# ASP.NET Core 3.1 ModelState validation fail for nullable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

The issue I am having, is that if you provide a null value for an item, that is nullable, the `ModelState.IsValid` flags a validation error saying "The value  ParentID is not valid for ParentID."

I want [int?] to allow null.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("common/menu-setting/add")]
public IActionResult AddMenuSetting(Menu model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewData["ParentMenus"] = _commonRepository.GetParentMenus();
        return View(model);
    }
    var returnValue = _commonRepository.AddMenu(model);
    if (!returnValue)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AddMenuSetting");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("MenuSetting");
}
```

Model:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentMenuName { get; set; }
    public int SortGroup { get; set; }
    public int Sort { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `Menu` classes and have you checked, that you use the correct one? The error you are receiving does not add up to the code you are showing us.

Comment: I agree with @Marco - Is it possible that you're trying to set `ParentID` to a string of "null"?

Comment: you may need to return value "" (empty string)  instead of "null".